# Developing algorithm what is calculating from coins the value in python

Tags: arrays, list

There are two arrays. For example:

```
"coins": [1, 2, 5, 10, 20, 50, 100, 200] 
"pieces": [140, 128, 132, 166, 18, 15, 120, 97]
```

and we want to calculate the price, for example (`"price": 5309`).
Therefore we have `140*1, 128*2, 132*5....97*200` money and we want use this money to pay the price.

We want to get rid of as much coins as possible. Any idea how to start?

Comment: Yeah loads, yourself?

Comment: I'm still just thinking about the algorithm. But no idea how to start..

Comment: @user3099995: You want to pay as much 200 coins as possible, don't you?

Comment: Nope. I want to use for the pay out as much pieces of coins as possible.

Comment: Ok, then - what sorts of coins do you want to pay in any case first?

Comment: From smallest. But we can only use coins what we have. (No change.)
And we want to pay the exact amount (not more).

Comment: In which case do you only pay the smallest coins? In which case the others?

Comment: For example the price (1746) would be: (140*1) + (128 * 2) + (132 * 5) + (69 * 10)

Comment: Ok, I think I understand the question [and I try to help you to find it on your own](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10811/how-do-i-ask-and-answer-homework-questions/10812#10812). Again, how do you decide if you pay the whole amount of '1' coins?

Comment: Google box picking algorithms.